# I need a query to find all the combinations of wrong entries

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table like this

```
 ID     FK   PREFERENCE
 78     54        1
 79     54        2
 80     54        3
 87     53        1
 88     53        2
 89     53        2 
 90     56        1
 91     56        2
 92     57        1
 93     58        1
```

for one FK the maximum possible Preferences are 3 and the exact values are 1,2 and 3. For a single FK we can have one 1,one 2and one 3 We can see in this table that for the FK 53 the Preferences are 1,2 and 2 and which is wrong entries.
I need a query to find all the combinations of wrong entries

Comment: Join the table to itself. Wherever fks and preferences are the same, and ids are different, you will have a clash. Then, if appropriate, consider providing a UNIQUE index on (FK,preference)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED**

```
SELECT t.*
  FROM Table1 t JOIN
(
  SELECT fk, preference
    FROM Table1
   GROUP BY fk, preference
  HAVING COUNT(*) > 1
      OR preference < 1
      OR preference > 3
) q  ON t.fk = q.fk 
    AND t.preference = q.preference
```

Output:

```
| ID | FK | PREFERENCE |
------------------------
| 88 | 53 |          2 |
| 89 | 53 |          2 |
```

Here is **[SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/ee006/2)** demo

Answer (score 0):

Below query will show you both rows in case of duplicates

```
SELECT *
FROM myTable as a
INNER JOIN myTable as b
ON a.FKS= b.FKS AND a.PREFERENCE= b.PREFERENCE AND a.ID <> b.ID
```

[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/f5ec0/8/0)

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
SELECT * FROM
(
SELECT fk, IF( LENGTH(GROUP_CONCAT( pre ORDER BY pre SEPARATOR '#')) > LENGTH( GROUP_CONCAT( DISTINCT pre ORDER BY pre SEPARATOR '#')), 0, 1 ) AS wrong
FROM test
GROUP BY fk
) AS wrongRow
WHERE wrongRow.wrong = 1;
```